# Iterate through list of LinkedHashMap in java

Tags: java, yaml

I am using LinkedHashMap to preserve the order while reading yaml file.

```
reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader(file));
read_contents = (Map<String, List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>>) reader.read();
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> all_items = read_contents.get("XYZ");
for (LinkedHashMap<String, Object> item : all_items) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : item.entrySet()) {
        <some code>
    }
}
```

Getting below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap

Comment: Casting != using

Comment: You can't change a `HashMap` to a `LinkedHashMap` just by casting it. They are different things.

Comment: You're approaching from the wrong angle. Once the parsing is done, it's too late to recover the order. You need to research how to have the *parser* preserve the order.

Comment: YamlReader is an open source project. Take a look at its source at https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/yamlbeans/YamlReader.java to see what if there's any way you can subclass to solve your problem.

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to Esoteric/yamlbeans to use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap inside YamlReader. If it gets accepted your problem will be solved.

Comment: The pull request was merged. If you use the latest version of the code from github, it will maintain the order of map entries.

Comment: @Jason Thanks! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Randeep just remember, you don't have to cast the returned map.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Thanks to comments, I now realize that ordering is important (I had missed this point in my original answer). The real problem is that the `YamlReader` is not using a `LinkedHashMap` internally, so the order has already been lost when you access each element of the list.

If you have access to code of the reader, maybe you could modify it so that it uses `LinkedHashMap` internally instead of `HashMap`. If you don't, maybe you could use [Jackson extension for YAML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/yaml).

---

Now my original answer...

The error says it all: a `HashMap` cannot be cast to `LinkedHashMap`. So, if you cast to `HashMap` instead of to `LinkedHashMap` you would be OK. But using specific implementations in client code is generally considered bad practice, because you don't know the concrete class of the map created by the `YamlReader`. Instead, you should just use the interface `Map`:

```
reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader(file));
read_contents = (Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>) reader.read();
List<Map<String, Object>> all_items = read_contents.get("XYZ");

for (Map<String, Object> item : all_items) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : item.entrySet()) {
        // <some code>
    }
}
```

This is safer, because you *program to the interface* and not to the concrete class, which is a basic programming principle.

With Java 8, you can achieve the same with more compact code:

```
all_items.forEach(item -> item.forEach((k, v) -> /* <some code> */));
```

Comment: This is all true, but doesn't solve the problem of preserving the order.

Comment: @Jason The order is already lost if the reader doesn't use `LinkedHashMap` internally. You can't do as if the reader were using `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` just by casting.

Comment: I think you missed the point: *I am using LinkedHashMap to preserve the order while reading yaml file.*

Comment: @shmosel I haven't missed the point. The problem is that the reader isn't using `LinkedHashMap` internally, so the order is already lost. But I will edit to say this, thanks.

Comment: Right, so your answer doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Jason I edited my answer to take your comment into account, thank you very much.